# how to use View data to fill in django forms

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have this view:

```
def edit(request):
    data = {}
    user = request.user
    data['requestor'] = user
    data['user'] = user
    data['member'] = models.Member.objects.get(User=user)
    data['Address'] = models.Address.objects.filter(User=user).filter(Primary=True).first()
    data['Phone'] = models.Phone.objects.filter(User=user).filter(Primary=True).first()
    data['Family'] = models.Family.objects.filter(Primary=data['member'])
    data['Sponsor'] = models.Family.objects.filter(Dependent=data['member']).first()
    data['rank'] = models.Promotion.objects.filter(User=user).latest('Date_Effective')
    data['form'] = forms.profile
    return render(request, "member/profile/page_user_edit.html", data)
```

I'm using this form to work with the view.  Of note, this form includes fields from multiple models, hence why it's not a `modelform`:

```
class profile(forms.Form):
    first_name = forms.CharField(label='First Name', max_length=50, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'md-input'}))
    last_name = forms.CharField(label='Last Name', max_length=50, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'md-input'}))
    profile_image = forms.FileField()
    Street = forms.CharField(label='Street Address', max_length=500, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'md-input'}))
    City = forms.CharField(label='City', max_length=50, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'md-input'}))
    State = forms.CharField(label='State', max_length=40, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'md-input'}))
    Zip = forms.CharField(label='Zip', max_length=20, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'md-input'}))
    County = forms.CharField(label='County', max_length=20, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'md-input'}))
    Country = forms.CharField(label='Country', max_length=50, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'md-input'}))
    Country_Code = forms.CharField(label='Country Code', max_length=5, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'md-input'}))
    Area_Code = forms.CharField(label='Area Code', max_length=5, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'md-input'}))
    Number = forms.CharField(label='Phone Number', max_length=20, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'md-input'}))
    Gender = forms.ChoiceField(choices=choices.GENDER_CHOICES)
    Height = forms.FloatField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'md-input'}))
    HairColor = forms.CharField(max_length=10, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'md-input'}))
    about = forms.Textarea()
    facebook = forms.CharField(max_length=50, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'md-input'}))
    twitter = forms.CharField(max_length=50, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'md-input'}))
```

in the template:

```
<div>
    <div class="uk-input-group">
        <span class="uk-input-group-addon">
            <i class="md-list-addon-icon uk-icon-facebook-official"></i>
        </span>
        <label>{{ form.facebook.label }}</label>
        {{ form.facebook }}
    </div>
</div>
```

The label and the form element shows on the page without a hitch, but I need the Current value in the form.  How do I push the current value stored in `data['member'].facebook` into the `form.facebook` field?

How do I accomplish this?
Thanks.

Comment: See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/initial-data/

Comment: can you explain?  How do I get the values into the form elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you first define a form, you can define it as so:

```
form = forms.profile({
       'first_name': first_name,
       'last_name': last_name,
       ...
       })
```

where the key is the name of the field in your form.

Also, just as an aside be careful when using python builtins like `zip` as fields in your forms or models